# Ionic: mouse event within OpenLayers wasn't handled

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, openlayers

I'm trying to handle double mouse click event on OpenStreetMaps, using the following code:

```
var map = new OpenLayers.Map("basicMap");

var mapnik = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();

var fromProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");

// Transform from WGS 1984
var toProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913");

// to Spherical Mercator Projection
var position = new OpenLayers.LonLat(13.41,52.52).transform(fromProjection, toProjection);

var zoom = 15;

map.addLayer(mapnik);
map.setCenter(position, zoom );

var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Markers" );

map.addLayer(markers);

OpenLayers.Control.Click = OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Control,
{
    defaultHandlerOptions:
    {
        'single': true,
        'double': true,
        'pixelTolerance': 0,
        'stopSingle': false,
        'stopDouble': false
    },

    initialize: function(options)
    {
        this.handlerOptions = OpenLayers.Util.extend({},this.defaultHandlerOptions);

        OpenLayers.Control.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);

        this.handler = new OpenLayers.Handler.Click(this, {'click': this.trigger}, this.handlerOptions);
    },

    trigger: function(e)
    {
        var lonlat = map.getLonLatFromViewPortPx(e.xy);

        alert("clicked");

        alert("Lat, Lon : " + lonlat.lat + ", " + lonlat.lng);

        markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(lonlat));
    },

    touchstart: function(e)
    {
        console.log();
    },

    touchend: function(e)
    {
        console.log();
    },

    handleSingle: function(e)
    {
        console.log();
    }
});

var control = new OpenLayers.Control.Click();
map.addControl(control);
control.activate();
```

However, after doing some testing. The message "clicked" was never displayed though I didn't find any error on the console while the map was correctly displayed.

So is there anything wrong within the code above? how is it possible to fix this issue?

Note: I'm using Ionic framework.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenLayers.Map does not fire a click event.

You should define a "Click" control (missing in OpenLayers 2), like this (from http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/click.html )

```
OpenLayers.Control.Click = OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Control, {                
    defaultHandlerOptions: {
        'single': true,
        'double': false,
        'pixelTolerance': 0,
        'stopSingle': false,
        'stopDouble': false
    },
    initialize: function(options) {
        this.handlerOptions = OpenLayers.Util.extend(
            {}, this.defaultHandlerOptions
        );
        OpenLayers.Control.prototype.initialize.apply(
            this, arguments
        ); 
        this.handler = new OpenLayers.Handler.Click(
            this, {
                'click': this.trigger
            }, this.handlerOptions
        );
    }, 
    trigger: function(e) {
        var lonlat = map.getLonLatFromPixel(e.xy);
        alert("You clicked near " + lonlat.lat + " N, " +
                                  + lonlat.lon + " E");
    }
});
```

Implement the trigger function, by putting your logic in it, or firing a click event.
Then use the control in your code

```
var control = new OpenLayers.Control.Click();
map.addControl(control);
control.activate();
```

You can find the click handler options here
http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Handler/Click-js.html

For example, if you need to handle double clicks, you should change the double property to true.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried the code you've suggested, but I'm still facing the same problem. Please take a look at my updated code on the question above.

Comment: Here's a fiddle with your code https://jsfiddle.net/fradal/0bfwvcyz/ . It seems to work as expected...

Comment: Yes, that works. But it doesn't work with my Ionic/Cordova app. That's odd.

Comment: There could be some other component that is stopping the touchstart and/or touchend events. I'd suggest to use the OpenLayers.debug.js version, add some console.log in OpenLayers.Handler.Click class, in functions touchstart, touchend and handleSingle. If possible, debug the handleSingle function

Comment: I tried debugging as you've recommended (see the updated code in the question above), but nothing got debugged in the console using the functions you described. however I'm receiving this error "Failed to load resource: Error resolving '': Name or service not known: http:///"

Comment: Those functions are not in OpenLayers.Control.Click but in OpenLayers.Handler.Click. My suggestion is to edit (temporary) OpenLayers.debug.js